# Enter text using "input" tag

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to enter data in specific fields using ID and class name, below is the HTML code.

[image]

Tried below code to enter data but getting error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set'

Someone please help me to doing this. please ask me if any additional information is needed.

```
Sub FillForm1()

Dim ie As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Const myPageTitle As String = "IE Window name"
  Const myPageURL As String = 
"https://www.mywebsite"

  Set ie = GetOpenIEByTitle(myPageTitle, False)

 ie.Visible = False
  DoEvents
  ie.Visible = True

 Set doc = ie.Document

doc.getElementById("ControlDataList3").getElementsByClassName("clearfix") 
(1).Value = "AA"

End sub
```

Comment: LIs do not have values. You mean `doc.getElementById("ControlDataList3").getElementsByClassName("INP")(1).Value = "AA"`

Comment: This is an editable field, where I want to fill the value

Comment: But you are accessing the LI, not the input field in the LI

Comment: As a blind shot: shouldn't it be `innerText` instead of `Value`?

Comment: @ mplungjan :could you suggest how to access the input field in this case?

Comment: @HTH : Sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: me sorry, I had to write `Value`. I edited my comment

Comment: @HTH : I tried it now but getting same error

Comment: @mplungjan I tried to access it by using classname "LNP" still not working

Comment: Why LNP? The input field's class is INP

Comment: I tried below... sorry for typo mistake.

doc.getElementById("ControlDataList3").getElementsByClassName("INP")(0).Value = "AA"

Comment: What's the url please? Also, remember to use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html rather than posting images.

Comment: @QHarr ; sorry to say it is an official site which is not accessible for everyone. I am glad to know  if want me to provide any other details

Comment: have you  tried to focus on the element before entering data? Also, have you tried firing/create attach and fire the events we can see in the image for the element?

Comment: No I didn't, can you please say bit more on this

Comment: please provide the code if possible

Comment: can someone please guide mi to focus on that element

Comment: Try and copy what @mplungjan wrote in his first response. Code you showed is still not correct

Comment: tried "doc.getElementById("ControlDataList3").getElementsByClassName("INP")(1).Value = "AA" brother... not working

Comment: @QHarr : Tried to focus on element using below code, but wasant helpful..

Set elem = doc.getElementsByClassName("menu")